# Whenever i Use CDATA in input XML aftet transforming with XSLT CDTA element values are corrupted

Tags: xml, xslt, mule

I am using Mule3.7 community edition, I am facing the xml parsing problem here is below.

In my input data i have element values with CDATA, and i am using xslt to transfer the xml, i am expecting my out put xml shoud also contain the CDATA.
however it is not working it is showing the currupted data whereever we have CDATA. I have tried with

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="text"/>
```

but still not working, it is showing the product issue.

"Value of {cdata-section-elements} must be a list of QNames in '{uri}local' notation (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)"

is there any other ways i can parse this xml.

```
<node>
    <subNode>
        <![CDATA[ HI THERE ]]>
    </subNode>
    <subNode>
        <![CDATA[ SOME TEXT ]]>
    </subNode>
</node>
```

Thank you
Lakshmi

Comment: When you say the output is "corrupted", can you show us what it looks like?

Comment: You would need to explain in what way you consider the resulting XML output to be "corrupted". In terms of the XML specification any `<subNode>   HI THERE  </subnode>` has only a lexical difference to e.g. `<subNode>   <![CDATA[HI THERE]]>    </subNode>`, the semantics are the same. There is some data like escaped markup that is more readable inside of a CDATA section but I am sure if the XSLT parsing and processing process eliminates a CDATA section then the output is properly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using element name instead `text()` in **XSLT 1.0** as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="subNode" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note:** If there are more elements other than `<subNode>` which are having `CDATA`, put them in `cdata-section-elements` **separated by a space**.